# Obtaining all combinations of Euclidean distance in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I would like to form a loss function in Tensorflow that relies on a matrix containing all combinations of (squared) Euclidean distances for a set of embeddings.  In numpy, like this:

```
# E is (batch_size,N,32)
N=100
D = np.zeros((batch_size,N,N))
for x in range(N):
  for y in range(N):
    D[:,x,y] = np.sum(np.square(E[:,x,:]-E[:,y,:]),axis=1)
```

How can I code this in Tensorflow/Keras without using the nested for loop, or no for loops at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do:

```
D = tf.reduce_sum((E[:, None, :] - E[:, :, None])**2, axis=-1)
```

D will be `(batch_size, N, N)`. This also works in numpy (obviously use `np.sum`), so you could use that to check equivalence to the loop version just to be sure.

This solution works via broacasting: `None` is used to insert axes such that a size-N axis is matched against a size-1 axis, and the latter is broadcast (repeated) to match the former. This results in all elements being compared to all others (per batch element). It's a little hard to describe in text and also difficult to visualize since we are dealing with four-dimensional tensors here...

Comment: Beautiful.  I was going down a similar path, but manually made the two expansions using K.repeat_elements and K.expand_dims.  This is more elegant.

Comment: One thing I forgot to mention is that this can be very memory-intensive, as you will have a `(batch_size x N x N x embedding_dimension)` for a moment. For large `N` this can get problematic, so it's kind of a trade-off between time vs memory.